# Index targeting on new list from old list

Tags: python, list, numpy

So let's say I have a list that looks like:

```
x = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I then have another list with indices that needs to be removed from list `x`:

```
x_remove = [1, 4, 5]
```

I can then use the `numpy` command `delete` to remove this from `x` and end up with:

```
x_final = np.delete(x, x_remove)
>>> x_final = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So far so good. Now I then figure out that I don't want to use the entire list `x`, but start perhaps from index 2. So basically:

```
x_new = x[2:]
>>> x_new = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I do however still need to remove the indices from the `x_remove` list, but now, as you can see, the indices are not the same placement as before, so the wrong items are removed. And same thing will happen if I do it the other way around (i.e. first removing the indices, and then use slice to start at index 2). So basically it will/should look like:

```
x_new_final = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]  (first use slice, and the remove list)
x_new_final_v2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]  (first use remove list, and then slice)
x_new_final_correct_one = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]  (as it should be)
```

So is there some way in which I can start my list at various indices (through slicing), and still use the `delete` command to remove the correct indices that would correspond to the full list ?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the x_remove list depending on the slice location. For example:

```
slice_location = 2
x = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
x_remove = [1, 4, 5]

x_new=x[slice_location:]
x_remove = [x-slice_location for x in x_remove if x-slice_location>0]
x_new = np.delete(x, x_remove)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
x_remove = [1, 4, 5]

for index,value in enumerate(x):
    for remove_index in x_remove:
        if(index == remove_index-1):
            x[index] = ""

final_list = [final_value for final_value in x if(final_value != "")]
print(final_list)
```

Try it this simple way...

Answer (score 0):

First let's explore alternatives for the simple removal (with out this change in starting position issue):

First make an `x` with unique and easily recognized values:

```
In [787]: x = list(range(10))
In [788]: x
Out[788]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

A list comprehension method - maybe not the fastest, but fairly clear and bug free:

```
In [789]: [v for i,v in enumerate(x) if i not in x_remove]
Out[789]: [0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Your `np.delete` approach:

```
In [790]: np.delete(x, x_remove)
Out[790]: array([0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

That has a downside of converting `x` to an array, which is not a trivial task (time wise).  It also makes a new array.  My guess is that it is slower.

Try in place removeal:

```
In [791]: y=x[:]
In [792]: for i in x_remove:
     ...:     del y[i]
     ...:     
In [793]: y
Out[793]: [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

oops - wrong.  We need to start from the end (largest index).  This is a well known Python 'recipe':

```
In [794]: y=x[:]
In [795]: for i in x_remove[::-1]:
     ...:     del y[i]
     ...:     
     ...:     
In [796]: y
Out[796]: [0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Under the covers `np.delete` is taking a masked approach:

```
In [797]: arr = np.array(x)
In [798]: arr
Out[798]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [799]: mask = np.ones(arr.shape, bool)
In [800]: mask[x_remove] = False
In [801]: mask
Out[801]: 
array([ True, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
In [802]: arr[mask]
Out[802]: array([0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

---

Now to the question of applying `x_remove` to a slice of `x`.  The slice of `x` does not have a record of the slice parameters.  That is you can't readily determine that `y = x[2:]` is missing two values.  (Well, I could deduce it by comparing some attributes of `x` and `y`, but not from `y` alone).

So regardless of how you do the delete, you will have to first adjust the values of `x_remove`.

```
In [803]: x2 = np.array(x_remove)-2
In [804]: x2
Out[804]: array([-1,  2,  3])
In [805]: [v for i,v in enumerate(x[2:]) if i not in x2]
Out[805]: [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This works ok, but that `-1` is potentially a problem.  We don't want it mean `the last element`.  So we have to first filter out the negative indicies to be safe.

```
In [806]: np.delete(x[2:], x2)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: in the future negative indices will not be ignored by `numpy.delete`.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[806]: array([2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

If `delete` didn't ignore negative indices, it could get a mask like this - with a `False` at the end:

```
In [808]: mask = np.ones(arr[2:].shape, bool)
In [809]: mask[x2] = False
In [810]: mask
Out[810]: array([ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False])
```